# Create alerts in Azure when Indexer fails in Azure Search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-alerts

I have multiple indexers which are indexing my index in a Azure Search. Sometime the indexers have failed due to various issues in the Source. I need to create alerts so that my operation team can act on the failures immediately. I tried creating alerts in the Azure Search, however I am not getting a proper Signal in "Configure Signal Logic" pane.

[image]

I need some guidance as to how to create alerts when indexers fail in Azure Search.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an alert with the following conditions:

- Signal name: Document processed count
- Greater than count 0

What is important, you need to add dimensions to check only failed documents from a certain index:

- Indexer name = my-index-name
- Failed = True

In the end, it should look like this:
[image]

An alert configured like this will fire as soon as a single document fails to be processed.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add diagnostic logging for your indexing activities, and then use [Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/). This doc article should be a good starting point: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-monitor-usage